# Computing the Hausdorff distance between any two subsets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $\emptyset\neq A,B\subseteq X$ . We define

$d_H(A,B)=\inf\{\epsilon>0: A\subseteq N_{\epsilon}(B),B\subseteq N_{\epsilon}(A)\}$, where $N_{\epsilon}(A)=\{x\in X:d(x,A)<\epsilon\}$.

The infimum of the empty set is asummed to be $\infty$, so we are not supposing that the sets are bounded.

I also know that

$d_H(A,B)=\max\{\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B),\sup_{b\in B}d(b,A)\}$

What I now want to prove is that

> $d_H(A,B)=\sup_{x\in X}|d(x,A)-d(x,B)|$

Without loss of generality we can suppose that $d_H(A,B)=\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B)$.

To show the $\le$ part, it would suffice to show that for every $x\in X$ we have

$|d(x,A)-d(x,B)|\le\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B)$

But I don't really have any idea on how to prove that inequality, nor the $\ge$ part either. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first inequality you mention, note
$$
d(x,B) \leq d(x,a)+ d(a,B) \leq d(x,a)+ d_H(A,B),
$$
for any $a\in A$ and $x\in X$. Taking infimum over $a\in A$ we get
$$
d(x,B)\leq d(x,A)+ d_H(A,B).
$$
By symmetry we also have
$$
d(x,A)\leq d(x,B)+ d_H(A,B).
$$
Combining these two inequalities we have
$$
|d(x,A)-d(x,B)|\leq d_H(A,B),
$$
for any $x\in X$.

For the reverse inequality notice that for any $a\in A$ we have
$$
d(a,B) \leq \sup_{x\in A} d(x,B)= \sup_{x\in A} |d(x,A)-d(x,B)|\leq \sup_{x\in X}|d(x,A)-d(x,B)|.
$$
By symmetry we also have an analogous inequality for every $b\in B$. Taking supremum over $a$ and $b$, and then the $\max$ between the two quantities we have the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much